# Using a Custom Style in My Code

Tags: html, css

[I'm trying to use this to change my checkbox and radio theme.](https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/aM32E)

The problem is that I simply can't check my checkbox. I click and it does nothing.

I just copied the css to my css/checkbox-style.css.

***[You can't see here if I check the checkbox it doesn't do anything](https://gyazo.com/a76011067a85a0340ac06433a33aeaf9). You'll need to copy the css to your pc and try.***

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <title>ATP</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/perfect-scrollbar/dist/css/perfect-scrollbar.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/checkbox-style.css">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.png" />
</head>

<body>
<div class="container-scroller">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="content-wrapper full-page-wrapper d-flex align-items-center auth-pages">
        <div class="card col-lg-4 mx-auto">
          <div class="card-body px-5 py-5">
            <h3 class="card-title text-left mb-3">Login</h3>
            <form action="Login" method="post">
              <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group">
                  <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control p_input" name="username" placeholder="Username">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group">
                  <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i></span>
                  <input type="password" class="form-control p_input" name="password" placeholder="Password">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
                <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary">
                  <label><input type="checkbox">Remember me</label>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="text-center">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block enter-btn">LOG IN</button>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/perfect-scrollbar/dist/js/perfect-scrollbar.jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/misc.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put your checkbox input outside the label like this:

```
<input type="checkbox">
<label>Remember me</label>
```